# Fetch multiple users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a list (uid's) of users that is connected to a group. On one page I want to list all usernames and emails of the users in the list.

What is the recommended way to fetch user data for each user? All I can find is in the admin sdk: `admin.auth().getUser(uid)`

1. Is there no way to fetch multiple users in one request? ex
   `admin.auth().getUsers([uid1, uid2, uid3])`?
2. Is there no way to do this in the client sdk?
3. If 1. is not possible, is it not quite easy to reach the limits? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#api_limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve the list of all users with the client SDK, but you can do it in two ways:

**Using the Firebase Realtime Database**

1. You can add a node of user names and emails, say `/users` in your database:

   ```json
   {
     "users": {
       "user1": {
         "username": "user1",
         "email": "user1@mail.com"
       },
       "user2": {
         "username": "user2",
         "email": "user2@mail.com"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then just query this node using `once('value')`:

   ```js
   const users = await firebase.database.ref('/userProfiles').once('value');
   console.log(users);
   ```

**Using a callable function and the Firebase Admin SDK**

1. Create an [HTTPS callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function), say `getAllUsers()`, that retrieves all users. The Firebase Admin SDK has a way to [list all users in batches of 1000](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).
2. Deploy the function using `firebase deploy --only functions:getAllUsers`.
3. Then call the function from the client:

   ```js
   const getAllUsers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getAllUsers');
   const users = await getAllUsers();
   console.log(users);
   ```

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

in your first suggestion; do you mean that I have to sync the users username+email from the firebase user (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) to the database? that seems a bit awkward? :)

Comment: If you decide to go with the first approach, then yes you have to sync the username and email. You can use Firebase security rules to ensure they are in sync; the auth data can be accessed via the `auth.token` object.

Comment: hmm okey, how do you mean I should sync with security rules?


there is a trigger for user-create: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation but none for user update

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was you still need to manually create/update the user name and email in the database node every time you create/update the user in auth. In your security rules, you can add a `.validate` rule to make sure the user name and email values are equal to the user name and email values from auth.